Pooling survey data with panel households
I am analyzing some data from a national survey. I am working with two sets of data for the same variable (wealth) and some of those households are panel (i.e. interviewed both times). Now I want to create a "single dataset" to estimate averages and distribution and I need a weighting scheme that accounts for the presence of panel households. Previous research on the same topic has suggested, for datasets of equal length, to use the following estimator for the average:
Y’=1⁄2{α1 Σi [yi1P /(np)]+(1-α1)Σi [yi1Q /(nq)]}+ 1⁄2 {β1 Σi [yi2P / (np)] + (1-β1) Σi [yi2Q / (nq)]}
where alpha is the weight of panel households at time 1, beta is the weight of panel households at time 2; p is the proportion of panel households and q=1-p. yi1P indicates ith observation of variable y at time 1 for a panel household.
The reserachers argue that in this setting α1 = β1 = p/(1+ ρq) (where ρ is the correlation coefficient), then the weights must be normalized and it's done. How do I do the same thing for datasets of different lenght?

Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Could you format your question using MathJax?
